# change the schema in quarkus hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

All is in the title:
I use java, hibernate and quarkus and a postgresql database

**How can I change the used database schema ? ** I don't want to use public but a custom schema name.

It's sound like an easy question, but I'm stuck and cannot find how to do it. I can't found it in any doc !

Thanks !

Comment: Just use an user with an schema assigned, you can also choose the schema with this  property https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema.

Comment: I think it depends on many things, where is your schema definition located inside your code? usually you configure the corresponding schema inside your application properties files, for example:database.db1.url: 'jdbc:postgresql://mydb.amazonaws.com:5432/mydbname?currentSchema=myschema&ssl=false;' another possibility is to define it in your entity class like this: @Table(name = "mytable", schema = "myschema")